# Node.js running Python Script doesn't return correct results

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, stdin, spawn

I am working on a Node.Js/Express app and need to call python script from route.

The route code:

```
router.get ('/new_bids',async (req, res) => {
  const { spawn } = require('child_process');
  const pyprog = spawn('python',["public/pythonscripts/new_bids_alert.py"]);
  pyprog.stdout.on('data', function(results) {
      console.log('results: %j', results[0]) 
  });
  pyprog.stderr.on('data', (results) => {
      console.log('err results: %j', results) 
  });
})
```

Python new_bids_alert.py:

```
 import sys
 em = 2
 print(em)
 sys.stdout.flush()
```

I expect to see:

> results: 2

But I get:

> results: 50

```
console.log(results)
```

returns:

> "Buffer 32 0d 0a"

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Should have use:

> JSON.parse(results)

instead of:

> results[0]

Comment: I have same issue.. I tried using JSON.parse.. but it throws error saying... unexpected token 'O' in JSON at position 0... 'O' because my output string from python code is like: 'Output is this...' Can u tell how to send result in json?

Comment: @KSK. Try JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))